# Finding the first integral of $\ddot{p}-\dot{p}/p+A/p-p^3=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading a paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9907210), and the author first gives the following differential equation:

$$\ddot{p}-\frac{\dot{p}^2}{p}+\frac{A}{p}-p^3=0$$

Later, they state that the first integral is given by

$$\dot{p}^2=p^4+Kp^2+A$$

where $K$ is a real constant. I can't get this; here is my attempt.

Multiply by $\dot{p}$ and integrate with respect to $s$, 
$$\int \dot{p}\ddot{p} ds=\int (\frac{\dot{p}^2}{p}-\frac{A}{p}+p^3)\dot{p}ds$$
Left hand side is good, $\frac{1}{2}\dot{p}^2$, but the right hand side is not:
$$\int (\frac{\dot{p}^2}{p}-\frac{A}{p}+p^3)\dot{p}ds=\int\frac{\dot{p}^3}{p}ds-A\ln(p)+\frac{1}{4}p^4.$$

Maybe my naive understanding of "first integral" is incorrect. Can anyone spot my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other method for autonomous second order ODE is to assume that for some specific solution one can find a relation $\dot p=v(p)$. Then the second order equation for $p$ transforms into a first order equation for $v$,
$$
vv'-\frac{v^2}p+\frac Ap-p^3=0.
$$
As is visible, this is linear in $u(p)=v(p)^2$, $$u'-\frac{2u}{p}+\frac{2A}{p}-2p^3.$$ The integrating factor is $\frac1{p^2}$, so that
$$
\frac{d}{dp}\frac{u}{p^2}=\frac{pu'-2u}{p^3}=2p-\frac{2A}{p^3}
\implies \frac{u}{p^2}=p^2+\frac{A}{p^2}+K
$$
Substituting backwards gives the expression for $K=\frac{\dot p^2}{p^2}-\frac{A}{p^2}-p^2$ as first integral.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is classified as an error.  But the integral $\int\frac{\dot{p}^3}{p}ds$ depends on the path, not just the initial and the final states.  To have an integral of motion, you should end up with an expression involving $p$ and $\dot{p}$ only, which is independent of the path you take.  I am presenting a derivation of the integral of motion in the cited paper.

Multiply both sides of the DE by $\frac{2\dot{p}}{p^2}$, we get
$$\frac{2\dot{p}\ddot{p}}{p^2}-\frac{2\dot{p}^3}{p^3}+\frac{2A\dot{p}}{p^3}-2p\dot{p}=0.$$
This is equivalent to
$$\frac{d}{ds}\left(\frac{\dot{p}^2}{p^2}-\frac{A}{p^2}-p^2\right)=0.$$
Thus, there exists a constant $K$ such that
$$\frac{\dot{p}^2}{p^2}-\frac{A}{p^2}-p^2=K.$$
That is, $$\dot{p}^2=p^4+Kp^2+A.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since the authors of the paper have worked out the first integral, it may be easier to read "backward" to see how it could be obtained.

By [definition](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/First_integral), the "first integral" of the DE is a function. It was given in a confusing way in the paper: 
$$
\dot p^2-p^4-Kp^2-A=0\tag{1}
$$
However, a hint from the paper to understand this is that $K$ is an "arbitrary real constant" and by definition, one should have
$$
\frac{d}{ds}\Phi(s,p)=0,
$$
where $\Phi$ denotes the first integral. Assuming $p^2>0$ and rewriting (1), one has
$$
\frac{\dot p^2}{p^2}-p^2-\frac{A}{p^2}=K.
$$
Now if one denotes 
$$
\Phi(s,p)=\frac{\dot p^2}{p^2}-p^2-\frac{A}{p^2},
$$
then one can check that indeed
$$
\frac{d}{ds}\Phi(s,p)
=\frac{2\dot p \ddot p-4p^3\dot p}{p^2}
+(\dot p^2-p^4-A)\frac{-2 p\dot p}{p^4}
=\frac{2\ddot p}{p^2}\left(
\ddot p -\frac{\dot p^2}{p}
+\frac{A}{p}
-p^3
\right)=0
$$